# visiting users Facebook ID w/out authorization?

Tags: authorization, facebook

I have a native (FBML) Facebook Application. I do not want to push the application visitors through the authorization process, however I do want to know their Facebook ID.

Is it possible to find the visiting users Facebook ID without requiring them to "Authorize" my Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before, I said it couldn't be done - but it can.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas

Read that, it's excellent. You need to decode the Base64 string and check the signature is correct, but other than that it gets you the user id among other stuff (like a temporary access token for graph.facebook.com)

REMEMBER : You need to change the settings in the Migrations tab for the information to come through! It's a vital step, but can be overlooked...

Hope this helps :)

Stuart

Comment: Yep, only in canvas apps as far as I know.

Comment: this is not true, you can only get the user_id AFTER they authenticate the application, regardless of whether it was an app or a tab.

Comment: The canvas guide reads "By testing for the presence of the user_id or oauth_token parameters, you can determine if the user has authorized your application". It does not say you can get the user id if the has not authorized.