# Facebook photo name showing on website

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

How can I get the user's photo and name to show on my website and save them in MySQL?

Comment: i think you'll need to be a little more specific...

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved by querying Graph API with id of user

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=name,picture
```

Results will contain name of the user and URL to his picture

Answer (score 0):

you need to get permission from user that uses your application.

once you have user_photos permision you can do whatever you want.

you can find all permission in here: extended permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms

and look out here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Answer (score 0):

Juicy is right that you can get that information. Turgut is not right about the authorisation as you can actually get that information for anyone if you know their Facebook Id. And therein lies the issue. If you are in a facebook app then facebook will post the user's id with the request for each page within the request object. But outside of facebook iframe apps you will need a way to query the users id. this can be done using the Facebook javascript api.

Here is some further reading:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=735915914

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/

[visiting users Facebook ID w/out authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990754/visiting-users-facebook-id-w-out-authorization)